# IIS 7.5 and node.js HTTP requests work on VPS but not outside the VPS

Tags: node.js, security, iis, get, vps

I hired a VPS (Windows Server 2008) with the aim of hosting a website. So i configured IIS 7.5 to run a html website. The website reads data (HTTP GET requests) from a little node.js application running on the same VPS on port 3000. I am getting the data as follows:

```
$.get( "http://localhost:3000/myfunction", function( data ) {
});
```

Inside the VPS if I go to chrome a type localhost it works perfectly. On the other hand if i insert the VPS's IP address the HTTP calls are not working...

Chromes JS Console says:

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED http://localhost:3000/myfunction
```

I need the node.js app not to be visible from outside the VPS so that sensible data in the code is not reachable...

Comment: Do you want your application accessible or not?  It seems that you do, but your last paragraph contradicts what you say.  At least, that's my read of it.  Can you clarify?

Comment: The application only should be accesible by the website and inside the VPS. The website does the HTTP requests to the node.js app internally and the website externally shows the template + the info obtained in the internal requests to the node.js app. I could open the port 3000 and make the node.js app visible from the outside. Then i wouldn't see the ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED error, but the node.js app would be exposed to attackers and i want to avoid that. That's why i want the node.js app stay just inside the VPS and let the website HTTP calls get the required info..I don't know if this is ok.

Comment: What powers the "website" portion?  You say you're making server-side calls to your Node.js application from it, but then why are you seeing errors in your browser console?

Comment: Because browers is making HTTP calls to localhost wich of course does not work on client-side.. Iv'e been looking around and i think that i need to reverse proxy a given url to the internal node.js app using IIS's ARR and URL Rewrite

Comment: I don't understand.  You say you don't want your Node.js app accessible from the outside, yet you want to make your Node.js app accessible from the outside?

Comment: Yes i want it accessible from the outside but just the HTTP calls (app.get functions result on my node.js app), sorry for my explanation. The reason is that in the code i have sensible data and i don't want to open a possibility for hackers to access to the code.

Comment: What else does your application do other than serve HTTP requests?

Comment: nothing else...just that..reads the data from a mongodb database and serves it

Comment: If you want your application accessible from the outside via HTTP, and your application only serves HTTP, then I don't understand the problem.  Why do you think people could get to your code if you're not serving that code?  It almost sounds like you're putting your Node.js application inside the document root of your web server, which wouldn't make any sense at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally managed to solve this using a reverse proxy (IIS's ARR and URL Rewrite) as it is explained in the following guide:

http://www.gitshah.com/2013/06/how-to-use-iis7-as-front-end-to-java.html